# sheets split multi-line result of importXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've written a python script to scrape a website for Item ID's for a game, then write them into a google sheet - from there the google sheet concatenates the ID's into one of their website's XML feed links, and I use importXML to pull the data I want to see.

However, it's returning the data in a series of 8+ lines within a single cell, I'd like to split this to return in 8 different columns. Is there a way to do this?

[What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aSid.png)

[What I would Like to See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9xgL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in Sheet1, create Sheet2 and in Sheet2 A1 enter:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

In Sheet2 B1 enter:

```
=Sheet1!B1
```

In Sheeet2 C1 enter:

```
=iferror(split(join(char(10),Sheet1!C1),char(10)))
```

Drag the formulas down as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a single formula:

`=split(IMPORTXML(A1,"//htmlTooltip"),char(10))` without having to use a second sheet.

[image: 1]]